# How To Make This Refer To My Clicked Object Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

```
button.setAttribute("onClick" , "addToCart()");
```

I wrote this line in creation of an element to do an action, but when i click it and deal with "this" it refers to window not the object

How can i fix this to make the click refer to my element in order to get some data from the parent ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `setAttribute` for event handling. Use `addEventListeners` instead. For now, you could make your function like this, which uses `event` object that gets passed when it's called on the triggering of the event, in this case `click`

```
function addToCart(e){
  var that = e.target; // use that instead of this
  // more code goes here
}
```

And then you could just set it to the `onclick` property

```
button.onclick = addToCart; // pass the function reference
```